# « This », l'interjection en argot d'internet ?

Tags: anglais, argot, interjections

> — At this point, a great ending would have been to have Bran get up
>   and walk. Might as well. [Rendu là, un bonne fin aurait été de de voir Bran se lever et marcher. Tant qu'à faire.]
>
> > — Dance Bran GOT the musical
> >  [*Dance Bran GoT*, la comédie musicale]
> >
> > > — [**This**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/this#Interjection).

Il s'agit d'un emploi de [*this*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/this) en argot d'internet sous forme d'interjection qui « *indicates the speaker's strong approval or agreement with the previous material* » [indique l'approbation marquée du locuteur ou le fait qu'il soit d'accord avec ce qui précède].

Y a-t-il un équivalent en français (on notera que *this* n'est pas exactement *that's it, well played/done, touché, right on*) ; le simple pronom démonstratif est-il suffisant ?

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this/that? use of "This"! Although I have no idea how to render it in French, the general notion behind it does remind me of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71812/hear-hear-ame-variations) and I'm almost tempted to add "This" (as well as "Word [up]" and "What s/he said") to my answer to that earlier ELL question.

Comment: `tout à fait d'accord` may be used in this situation

Comment: @OznOg Je t'invite à l'ajouter en réponse, et à valider si variante sans _d'accord_ marche aussi à ton avis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De nombreuses périphrases pourraient convenir, mais pour rester dans l'idée d'un argot internet, je propose ceci :

`Je plussoie.`

Sinon, quelque chose comme `Voilà !` ou `Exactement` conviendrait.

En revanche, une traduction littérale de `This` ne marchera pas.